# A function with undefined argument numbers which call printf()

Tags: c, console, printf, curses

Im trying to create a function which call printf (printw in my case im using curses) and the reason why im doing this because i want to pass the color and do the refresh in the same function so instead of writing 3 lines everytime i wwant to show something i only have to do it once with one function so the function im going to create look like this in C :

```
void outputConsole(int color_id, const char* a, ...)
{
    attron(COLOR_PAIR(2));
    printw(a,...);
    refresh();
}
```

Comment: You'll need a function such as `vprintw()` (does it exist; what alternatives are there?), and `<stdarg.h>` and `va_list args;` and `va_start(args, a);` and `va_end(args);`.  If `vprintw()` is not available, you're gonna have to work hard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that using [`vw_printw`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36784_01/html/E36880/vw-printw-3xcurses.html#REFMAN3Cvw-printw-3xcurses). Solution is

```
void outputConsole(int color_id, const char* a, ...)
{
    attron(COLOR_PAIR(2));
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, a);
    vw_printw(stdscr, a, args);
    va_end(args);
    refresh();
}
```

Also while declaring to ensure compiler format string checking you can write like this

```
void outputConsole(int color_id, const char* a, ...)
#ifdef __GNUC__ 
       __attribute__(( format (printf, 2, 3)));
#else 
       ;
#endif
```

Comment: You wouldn't call `initscr()` in a function like this, would you?  `printw()` probably writes to `stdscr` — so your wrapper code probably should, too.  There's also a distinct probability that `printw()` is a macro defined over another function — perhaps `wprintw()`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler.: I have little exposure to this - but I know how to use `printf` with vaargs - and now I checked manual. From this I inferred this answer. And `stdscr` also hold the same value - so we can use that too.

Comment: Those man pages aren't explicit about what functions like `addstr` or `printw` use as a window.  Not helpful.  (Or, not helpful in isolation; if you go to https://linux.die.net/man/3/ncurses, part way down it says "routines not starting `w` write to `stdscr`" — roughly.) Using `initscr()` is like using `fopen()` each time you write to a file — not a good idea.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler.: Seems so. Let me dig a bit to get proper source. As far as I rememeber - using `stdscr` will be a good choice over here. But let me check.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler.: Here you can find a bit clear - but still not suitable to know what `win` points to. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36784_01/html/E36880/vwprintw-3xcurses.html

Comment: BTW, if you are using gcc I'd add a `__attribute__ ((format (printf, 1, 2)))` *on the declaration* (enclosed in an `#ifdef __GNUC__` for portability) - compiler format string checking is extremely valuable, you wouldn't want to lose it on your `printf` wrappers. Also, `-Werror=format` if you aren't already using it.

Comment: @MatteoItalia.: I am a noob on using ncurses. Can you be bit more specific? Or maybe if you can show where I can read about this change?

Comment: @coderredoc: it's not about ncurses, but about gcc. It's a gcc function attribute instructing the compiler that the function is a "printf-like" in the interpretation of the format string and variadic arguments, so that it can check if they match. You can read about it here: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#Common-Function-Attributes

Comment: Yeah, like that, although I'd ifdef just the attribute (not the whole declaration).

Comment: @MatteoItalia.: I know so little and I am ashamed now. `void outputConsole(int color_id, const char* a, ...) #ifdef __GNUC__ __attribute__(( format (printf, 2, 3))); #endif` like this?

Comment: @coderredoc: nothing to be ashamed about, this kind of compiler specific extensions are not so widespread knowledge.

Comment: @MatteoItalia.: Thanks for the support. I learnt a nice thing today.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler.: Thanks for the comment.